# Android: How to display Customer Name with Intent.ACTION_CALL

Tags: android

How do I display customer name while dialing call using Intent.ACTION_CALL?  currently it only showing the phone number while the call is in progress.

Here is my current code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL 
Uri.parse("tel:" + txtViewContactPhoneNumber.getText() ));    
startActivityForResult(intent, contactID);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke startActivityForResult, you are effectively handing over control to whoever gets the Intent.

You can't control how the receiving application acts on the Intent.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  When press dial from contacts, it displaying both Customer Name and phone number.  Are there any extra values that I can pass it Action_Call?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing as a part of the standard ACTION_CALL documentation. Different applications (dialers in your case) might have different extra values, but there is no standard data. Besides, I would expect any decently well written dialer to show the name of the person whose number you are dialing.